# How to close drawer on click in React Native Navigation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am using react material design theme

but when i click drawer navigation button on mobile view
it is not closing automatically

Like 
`(onClick={handleClose})`

how can i fix this issue for my drawer navigation menu???

here is my code for your reference.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kwl9U.png)

Comment: I've answered your question, but next time it would be preferable if you just pasted the code in a code block.

Comment: here is my issue code post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59597226/how-to-close-drawer-on-click-in-react-material-ui-theme

Answer (score 0):

The Drawer component receives a `open` prop. Toggling this prop too false will close the drawer.

if the `open` prop lives in the state, than the `handleClose` method should do something like:

```
this.setState({ open: false }):
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe from reading the documentation that `onClose` is only triggered after the drawer finishes closing.

I would use the tapToClose prop. Like `tapToClose={true}`. I believe this will fix it.

If this doesn't:

Try not using the onClose prop. Toggle the `open` state property through a button with `this.setState({ open: false })`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59597226/how-to-close-drawer-on-click-in-react-material-ui-theme here is my issue code