# How to close drawer on click in react material UI theme?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am using react material design theme

but when i click drawer navigation button on mobile view it is not closing automatically

Like `(onClick={handleClose})`

how can i fix this issue for my drawer navigation menu???

> ```
> const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({   drawer: {
>   // width: 240,
>   width: '100%',
> }})
>
>   const Navigation = props => {   const { open, variant, onClose,
>   className, ...rest } = props;
>
>  const classes = useStyles();
>
> const pages = [
> {
>   title: 'Home',
>   href: '/dashboard',
>   icon: <HomeOutlinedIcon />
> },
>
> {
>   title: 'Student Info',
>   href: '/studentinfo',
>   icon: <SchoolOutlinedIcon />
> },
> {
>   title: 'Gradebook',
>   href: '/gradebook',
>   icon: <BookOutlinedIcon />
> },
> {
>   title: 'Student Attendance',
>   href: '/studentattendance',
>   icon: <CheckBoxOutlinedIcon />
> },
> {
>   title: 'Fee Payment',
>   href: '/feepayment',
>   icon: <PaymentOutlinedIcon />
> },
>
>
>  return (
>    <Drawer
>      anchor="left"
>      classes={{ paper: classes.drawer }}
>      onClose={onClose}
>      open={open}
>      variant={variant}
>
>    >
>     <div
>       {...rest}
>       className={clsx(classes.root, className)}
>      >
>     {/* <Profile /> */}
>
>     <TopNavigation
>       className={classes.nav}
>       pages={pages}
>     />
>     <Divider className={classes.divider} />
>     {/* <UpgradePlan /> */}
>     </div>
>     </Drawer>   ); };
>
>  Navigation.propTypes = {   className: PropTypes.string,   onClose:
>    PropTypes.func,   open: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,   variant:
>    PropTypes.string.isRequired };
>
>   export default Navigation;
> ```

Comment: anyone can help for above???

Comment: waiting for anyone support

Comment: This looks like child component, you have to implement onClose function from the parent component. **onClose** function will set state **open** to **false**

Answer (score 1):

I think you missing something on parent component is either onClose implementation or open state, but parent component has to look like:

```
state = {
  open: false
}

onClose = () => {
 this.setState({ open: false });
}

render() {
 const { open } = this.state;
 return (
  <Navigation open={open} onClose={this.onClose} {...this.props} />
 )
}
```